# How to move pageviewcontroller from cell touch

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a few questions, help me please.

I want to move viewcontroller of UIPageViewController if I touch CollectionViewCell on didSelectItemAt Delegate protocol.
Please help me how to write or modify the below code.

Thank you.

[View Page]

```
class ListPageViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var openSlideMenuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet weak var menuCollectionView: UICollectionView!

let menuCell = menuViewCell()
let menuItemNames = ["menu1", "menu2", "menu3", "menu4"]



@IBAction func moveHomeVC(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()    

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Define NavigationBar
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    var nevigatorHeight: CGFloat = 0
    nevigatorHeight = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)!

    //print("Navigation Height : \(nevigatorHeight)")

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Define Menu
    menuCollectionView.delegate = self
    menuCollectionView.dataSource = self

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return menuItemNames.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "menuCellId", for: indexPath) as! menuViewCell

    cell.menuLabel.text = menuItemNames[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    //print("This page number is \(rootPage.viewControllerList.index(of: viewController)!).")
}   
}

[PageView]

import UIKit

class RootPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

lazy var viewControllerList: [UIViewController] = {
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RedVC")
    let vc2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BlueVC")
    let vc3 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YellowVC")
    let vc4 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GrayVC")

    return [vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4]
}()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self

    if let firstViewController = viewControllerList.last {
        self.setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let currentPage = viewControllerList.index(of: viewController)

    print("This page number is \(currentPage!) on your before gesture.")

    guard let vcIndex = currentPage else { return nil }

    let previousIndex = vcIndex - 1

    guard previousIndex >= 0 else { return nil }

    guard viewControllerList.count > previousIndex else { return nil }

    return viewControllerList[previousIndex]

}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let currentPage = viewControllerList.index(of: viewController)


    print("This page number is \(currentPage!) on your after gesture. ")

    guard let vcIndex = currentPage else { return nil }

    let nextIndex = vcIndex + 1

    guard viewControllerList.count != nextIndex else { return nil }

    guard viewControllerList.count > nextIndex else { return nil }

    return viewControllerList[nextIndex]
}



}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpJBd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)` method from `UIPageviewController`.

Similar question:- [How to properly advance a PageViewController in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443549/how-to-properly-advance-a-pageviewcontroller-in-swift?rq=1)